# Communication between two Arduinos over RF module

Tags: arduino-uno

I want to communicate Arduino A to Arduino B by using RF module. But my RF module (Tx- XLPCF20, Rx- XY-R01A) only consist of 4 pins of data pin where it can send 4 bits of data only. So, I want to develop a new encoding to send data by using 4 bits of data. How should i do for the coding since I don't want to use serial write for coding. Any suggestion? Help me please. If u can give me the coding, I'm beyond thankful.

Answer (score 1):

You have 4 channels of raw HIGH/LOW communication.  How you use them is up to you.

The simplest method is to use an asynchronous serial protocol:

- Use Serial: Connect the TX of one Arduino to channel 1 at the TX, and RX channel 1 to RX on the other Arduino
- Use SoftwareSerial: The same as above but you choose the pins
- Use VirtualWire: very similar to SoftwareSerial

For higher speeds, since you have 4 channels, you could use a *synchronous* serial communication protocol. It should be perfectly possible to connect three of the channels to SPI and communicate as if it were talking directly to an SPI device - one channel to SCK, one to MOSI and one to SS. The other end has SCK, MOSI and SS but running in slave mode.

No need to "invent" a 4-bit protocol, it's too much work.